# How to access static resources(WEB-INF) folder from and write tests for it

Tags: spring, junit, resources, web-inf

I need to load a file resource when starting my server. 
So I placed the file under webapp/WEB-INF.

The problem is that the unit tests fail.

I try to load the file using:

```
URL url = Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
File file = new File(url.getFile());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

But the class loader does not find the file. It seems like it is looking for it at

```
file:/C:/<local path>/<my project>/target/test-classes/
```

- There are different contexts for during normal mode and test mode

I tried also the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649550/162345) but it didnt work

Comment: Does the file have to live in WEB-INF? Or could it live in WEB-INF/classes?

Answer (score 0):

It is a relatively complex process how classpaths are overriden and resolved in tomcat, but the simple answer is that `WEB-INF` is **not** part of the classpath so you can't access it from your webapp like that. `WEB-INF/classes` is where you can read files from.

Probably you want to read through [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application) which should give you all the potential solutions